# Populate TableView from Json List

Tags: c#, arrays, list, uitableview, xamarin

I'm working on a Xamarin project for iOS in C#.

I've got a Json file that contains 4 items. I want them to populate the TableView but only the last item in the Json file is shown.

This is how I get the List from the Json file:

```
StreamReader strm = new StreamReader (filePath);
response = strm.ReadToEnd ();

List<Field> items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Field>>(response);
```

To show these items in a TableView I created an array like this:

```
int count = items.Count;
string[] tableItems = new string[count];
```

I'm trying to fill the array like this:

```
foreach(Field item in items)
{
    tableItems = new string[] { item.Value };
}
table.Source = new TableSource(tableItems);
Add(table);
```

This is TableSource:

```
public TableSource (string[] items)
{
    TableItems = items;
}
```

Is this even possible and how can I achieve it so my Json items are in a TableView?

EDIT

This is the Json file. I parsed it just in a ViewController and it worked but not in a TableViewController..

```
[{
'id': 0,
'type': 'textField',
'value': 'Vul hier je voornaam in.',
'extra': ''
},{
'id': 1,
'type': 'textField',
'value': 'Vul hier je achternaam in.',
'extra': ''
},{
'id': 2,
'type': 'textField',
'value': 'Vul je gebruikersnaam in.',
'extra': ''
},{
'id': 3,
'type': 'textField',
'value': 'Vul je wachtwoord in.',
'extra': 'password'
}]
```

Comment: Could you post the JSON you're trying to deserialise?

Comment: I checked the Length of tableItems in the foreach loop and it is always 1. The problem is in there somewhere..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could take advantage of the C# features like LINQ and make it a much simpler process:

```
        table.Source = new TableSource(
            JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Field>> (response).
            Select (a => a.Value).
            ToArray ()
        );
```

The problem with your current code is that if the Id's are not 0 indexed and sequential you will run into an exception. If you want to sort the items then you can add sorting easily:

```
        table.Source = new TableSource(
            JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Field>> (response).
            OrderBy(s => s.Id).
            Select (a => a.Value).
            ToArray ()
```

Comment: What if I need to select multiple values from List<Field> and also combine it with a Where function?

Comment: It's an enumerable so you can tag along anything you wish. Do you want the source to contain now a collection of Field's? Hre is a link that might be helpful: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable_methods(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

I already fixed it with examples from this article: http://www.dotnetperls.com/string-array

My foreach loop is now the following for everybody who has the same problem:

```
foreach(Field item in items)
{
    tableItems[item.Id] = item.Value;
}
```